# Difference between saga and service bus?

Tags: microservices, azureservicebus, saga

Upgrading skills from Azure Service bus to Rabbit MQ + Mass Transit. Please bear with me.
I have convoluted understanding in mind about Saga and State Machine (Automatonymous). Are they synonym of each other.

> Does the name SAGA originates from integrated state machine functionalities
>   in service bus? Can we say Saga is superset of service bus?

As Azure does not have integrated state machine in their service bus.

Comment: Wait, upgrading from Service But *to* RMQ+MT?  You mean the other way around, right?

Comment: Have a read of this https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/?version=core_7 HTH

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, Sagas are use for the transactions, for example among microservices, to maintain consistency between them.

> You have applied the Database per Service pattern. Each service has
>   its own database. Some business transactions, however, span multiple
>   service so you need a mechanism to ensure data consistency across
>   services. For example, lets imagine that you are building an
>   e-commerce store where customers have a credit limit. The application
>   must ensure that a new order will not exceed the customer’s credit
>   limit. Since Orders and Customers are in different databases the
>   application cannot simply use a local ACID transaction.
>   Reference: http://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html